# Cannot find symbol in class Pemohon

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

i have a class which function is to validate the input to the database befor it's insert into the other database... it's look like this :
1. Database Penduduk using oracle 9i
2. Database Pemohon using MySQL

here is the class i used to validate

this class is in data.KTP which is call Oracle 9i Database

```
public class KTP {

public KTP (){

}

private Connection connection;
private String sql;

public KTP(Connection connection) {
    this.connection = connection;
}


public boolean CekNikPadaKtp(String nikPemohon) throws Exception {
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        boolean cekNik = true;
        String nikKtp = "";
        sql = "SELECT NIK, TGL_BERLAKU FROM SIAKOFF.VW_KTP_WNI A, DUAL B "
                + "where TGL_BERLAKU < to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY') AND NIK=?";
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, nikPemohon);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            nikKtp = rs.getString("nik");
        }
        rs.close();
        if (nikKtp.equals("")) {
            cekNik = false;
        }
        return cekNik;
    } finally {
        ConnectionUtil.closePreparedStatement(ps);
    }
}
```

}

and this one is from the other which is call from the above

```
public class Pemohon {

private Connection connection;
private String sql;

public Pemohon(Connection connection) {
    this.connection = connection;
}

public String savePemohon(TblPemohon tp) throws Exception {
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        if (CekNikPadaKtp(tp.getKtpPemohon())) {
            sql = "insert into pemohon"
                + "(noktp_pemohon,nama_depan,nama_belakang,tempat_lahir_pemohon,tgl_lahir_pemohon,sex,"
                + "agama,status_perkawinan,pekerjaan_pemohon,nama_jalan_pemohon,rt_pemohon,rw_pemohon,kelurahan_pemohon,"
                + "kecamatan_pemohon,kab_ko_pemohon,provinsi_pemohon,pos_pemohon,telp_pemohon,kewarganegaraan_pemohon) "
                + "values("
                + "?,?,?,?,?,"
                + "?,?,?,?,?,"
                + "?,?,?,?,?,"
                + "?,?,?,?,?)";
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, tp.getKtpPemohon());
        ps.setString(2, tp.getNamaDepanPemohon());
        ps.setString(3, tp.getNamaBelakangPemohon());
        ps.setString(4, tp.getTempatLahirPemohon());
        ps.setString(5, tp.getTanggalLahirPemohon());
        ps.setString(6, tp.getJenisKelamin());
        ps.setString(7, tp.getAgamaPemohon());
        ps.setString(8, tp.getStatusPerkawinan());
        ps.setString(9, tp.getPekerjaanPemohon());
        ps.setString(10, tp.getNamaJalanPemohon());
        ps.setString(11, tp.getRtPemohon());
        ps.setString(12, tp.getRwPemohon());
        ps.setString(13, tp.getKelurahanPemohon());
        ps.setString(14, tp.getKecamatanPemohon());
        ps.setString(15, tp.getKabupatenPemohon());
        ps.setString(17, tp.getProvinsiPemohon());
        ps.setString(18, tp.getKodePosPemohon());
        ps.setString(19, tp.getTelpPemohon());
        ps.setString(20, tp.getKewarganegaraanPemohon());
        ps.execute();
        return "success";
        } else {
            return "Info : nik pemohon belum ada di tabel ktp !";
        }
    } finally {
        ConnectionUtil.closePreparedStatement(ps);
    }
}
```

}

Help me please...

Comment: your starting letter 'c' in CekNikPadaKtp has the difference in the call and the definition.

Comment: please, translate your variable and method names to english before asking the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public boolean CekNikPadaKtp(String nikPemohon)` is an instance method in your `KTP` class and now you want to call it inside your class `Pemohon`

then first you need to create an instance of `KTP` class and then invoke the method, like

```
 try{
 KTP k = new KTP(connection); // edited
 if (k.CekNikPadaKtp(tp.getKtpPemohon())) {
 ... remaining code....
```

You cannot call an instance method of some other class without creating an instance/object of that class.

I think you are not clear enough with classes, objects, instance methods, static methods, etc. and various other concepts in java.

So better first clear these and then try, you will find it much easy.

Comment: hm... i try to add the code like you say but still got error constructor KTP error cannot be applied to given types.

Comment: how can i send my classes in this comment ??

Comment: if you are able to edit your question, then put the classes in the question

Comment: there in class Pemohon in line 
if (CekNikPadaKtp(tp.getKtpPemohon())) --> CekNikPadaKtp error cannot find symbol